# How to create Q & A panel in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new in wordpress and I am in a fix which way should I approach.

I have a wordpress site in which some question have to be stored which will come from another website in `GET` method.

1. The questions should be stored in a database table.
2. I can access the questions from admin panel
3. I can answer the question and the answer will be stored in the database table
4. The answer should also be sent to another website in `GET` method

How I achieve this? I have found `custom_post_type` and many other stuffs. But I am in a fix how to approach step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you study the following documentation and proceed to asking different questions for each step that you actually face problems with.

- [HTTP API](http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API)
- [XML-RPC Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)
- [Posting by Email](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_to_your_blog_using_email)